# How to display "loading..." Message lasting until a function completely done in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loading

I am a little confused of using some possible solutions for displaying a "loading..." message that starts when a function calls and ends after it finishes. Here is my code sample:

**HTML**

```
<div id="demo">
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Go" onclick="myFunction()" />
<table id="simpleTable">
</table>
</div>
<div id="content">   //a large text here
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
function myFunction(){
//a set of lines that convert words inside "content" to array, count them and put them raw by raw in "simpleTable"
}
```

The question is where to place a function that shows "Loading" message while the long operation is implementing and hide it after it is done.

**update**

I have tried some plugins for that, but they only work when there is a fast operation. In delay conditions such as large texts, it does not work. FYI I don't want to set a fixed timeout, because I don't really know how long it would take to be executed.

Answer (score 2):

Just add loading before the lines of code to be executed and clear it at the end of the function:

```
function myFunction(){

showLoading();

//a set of lines that convert words inside "content" to array, count them and put them raw by raw in "simpleTable"

clearLoading();
}
```

Comment: This will most likely not work as the UI will be locked up until myFunction() finishes. You'd have to use setTimeout to release it on each of the inner calls.

Comment: @atheaos I think you are right. The situation looks like what you described.